# Is this true? "It is not possible to get source code of a page which the client requests"

Tags: javascript, php, http, server, client

The client visits x.com

Inside x.com, y.com is requested when the client opens up x.com in an iframe or any other way.

So the client is actually the one who requested y.com here. The client directly gets the source code of y.com

That's why x.com cannot reach the source code y.com has in a way that the client has. (it's not a static website obviously)

To get the source code, x.com must request y.com, inside x.com's server.

"It is not possible to get source code of a page which the client requests"

Is this true? How can x.com get the source code of y.com without requesting it by itself?

---

I suppose that could be dangerous. I'm just trying to get contents of reddit.com  and change its UI without requesting reddit pages in my server or without using API. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Imagine you have your online banking open in a browser tab. You're logged-in and your bank page prominently displays how much money you have. Now you open x.com in another tab, and x.com loads your bank site in a frame. If x.com would have access to that iframe, its owner could easily read your private data. That's why it's forbidden.

Comment: Yes, it is true. The only legitimate way to retrieve response from a server is to submit HTTP request to the server.

Comment: @georg  can you see the update?

Comment: @AlexBlex  can you see the update?

Comment: @mmswe: no, there's no way.

Comment: The only way is to extend client. e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greasemonkey

Comment: I imagine the request is made by $.load or $.ajax or something of that sort? Isn't the 1st parameter of the success callback of both functions the source you're looking for?

Comment: why not simply use the reddit API? Authenticate the user and get the contents directly.

Comment: i've read that reddit bans API users without any notice and they have a tendency to ignore such developers.